# How to use Java sdk in react native

Tags: reactjs

I have a sdk file which is built using Java. I need to use this sdk in my react native app. Can you please let me know how to use the Java sdk in react native

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this might help. I am still learning how it works tho. I am new to RN.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

https://cmichel.io/how-to-create-react-native-android-library

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).